# Reassigning a multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

I am creating a function that will take a char parameter and translate that into a bool[8][8] array. Here's what my function looks like right now:

```
void DotMatrix::displayCharacter(char c, bool doScrolling, int milliseconds){
bool pixelMap[8][8];
if (c == 'A'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'B'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'C'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'D'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'E'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'F'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'G'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'H'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'I'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'J'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'K'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'L'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'M'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'N'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'O'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'P'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'Q'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'R'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'S'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'T'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'U'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'V'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'W'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'X'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'Y'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == 'Z'){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0}
    };
} else if (c == ' '){
    pixelMap = {
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
}
if (doScrolling == 1){
    scrollPixels(milliseconds, pixelMap);
} else {
    displayPixels(milliseconds, pixelMap);
}
```

}
However, when I run this code in my program, it returns:

```
error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a much better approach:

```
 bool pixelmap[26][8][8] = {
  {
    {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0}
  },

  // No, no need to repeat everything.
};

if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
{
   auto p=pixelmap[c-'A'];

   // ...
}
```

No need to copy or assign anything.

Comment: Will this load 26 8x8 arrays, essentially? Because I have a limit of about 2048 bytes of RAM.

Comment: Well, yes. Arrays don't appear out of thin air. Technically, it's a single, three-dimensional array, 26x8x8 which, thanks to modern mathematics, will take exactly the same amount of space as 26 individual 8x8 arrays. And, if you declare it as static, it won't even consume your stack space! Plus as an extra bonus, if you order now, you'll save the cost of doing 26 consecutive comparisons, and you'll get one, small, mathematical expression instead. What a deal!

Comment: I guess all it needs is 26*8*8 bytes

Comment: If you can do it in Arduino-space, consider `std::vector<bool>`. It may be implemented to bit pack. By the way, are you sure you have ab 8-bit `bool`?

Comment: Another thought. If those are statically allocated and can be constant, they might not take any RAM at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't explicitly assign values to an array during runtime using an initializer list.

Try this:

```
 auto tempMap = std::initializer_list<bool>({
    {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0});
 std::copy(tempMap.begin(), tempMap.end(), pixelMap);
```

If you're eventually just going to write this to a video frame buffer, consider using char instead of bool. That will simplify things quite a bit, though your code won't look as nifty ;)

Comment: my bad, copy paste nonsense. Fixed, thanks @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Problem is, I'm using arduino, so I cannot use the standard library like in normal c++, so I was trying to find a way around that. However, as another alternative, would it be feasible to simple loop through all the values and reassign each one?

Comment: But how much strain would it put on the system? Because I am doing multiplexing, and I would like these intermediate calculations to be as quick as possible, somewhere less than a few microseconds.

Comment: See @SamVarshavchik's answer above. No copying required if you have the memory space.

Comment: As for doing 64 assignments individually, it's a lot of code, but will not take any significant amount of time to complete. Wouldn't worry about performance at all.

Comment: That's entirely the point. I have only 2048 bytes of RAM and 26 of these large arrays would come dangerously close to that limit.

Comment: If you're eventually just going to write this to a video frame buffer, consider using byte/char instead of bool. That will simplify things quite a bit, though your code won't look as nifty ;)